# Repair corrupt tabular data

Tags: algorithm, csv, rounding-error

I have a csv file containing a column of 64bit integers where some have been truncated due to floating point precision issues.

Here is an example

```
id                       name
-----------------------------
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028281378205 'GSS Glasgow'
387028000000000 'GSS Glasgow'
387028000000000 'GSS Glasgow'
```

The first 6 digits are always correct however, sometimes the remainder are zero'd.

The second column is always identical for both correct and incorrect ids.

I can't guarantee that the correct id will be parsed before an incorrect one, so I'm struggling to think how to lay this problem out. I would really appreciate some ideas.

There's 6000 rows with 600 different 'names'. I can program this in python, perl, php, I just need to figure out a bullet proof approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read all lines into a list.
2. Group the list by `name`.
3. In every group look for the correct `id` and fix all corrupted `id`s in that group.
4. Save the list.